# WCF message: protocol in To element changes

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, soapheader, endpointbehavior

I have a WCF service to consume in .NET. As per requirement the Action element in the header has to be **"http://abc"** and the To element has to be **"ws://xyz"** in order for the service to recognize and respond to the request. The soapAction of the operation is however blank in WSDL and it can't be changed.

My service configuration built programmatically is this:

- text message encoding binding with Soap11 envelope version and WSAddressing10 addressing version
- no security biding
- http transport binding

The setup I found achieving this requirement is "ws://xyz" as the endpoint URL and Request.Headers.Action set to "http://abc" in BeforeSendRequest using a message inspector added using an endpoint behaviour attached to the endpoint. Then I also attach a ClientViaBehavior with the URL of "http://abc".

On my development machine this causes as required

```
<a:Action>http://abc</a:Action>
<a:To>ws://xyz</a:To>
```

However on the test server it generates

```
<a:Action>http://abc</a:Action>
<a:To>http://xyz</a:To>
```

I don't know exact configuration of the server but I believe it is Windows server as is my development box. Does the same code generates different messages on two different machines or how else would I achieve this? I should also say it worked fine for several weeks and stopped last Monday.

*I have found the following later:
The test server has .NET 4.5 on it as well as another machine I tried it on (also failed). The dev machine where it works fine has just .NET 4.0 on it which would suggest it could have something to do with it. However I have no evidence it is caused by .NET 4.5 as it was installed several weeks before the problem appeared. Moreover there have been no Windows updates since it stopped to work!
I've also tried to set the To element in my ClientMessageInspector implementation but the protocol still gets flipped to http.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the BeforeSendRequest is not called due miss configration of your service bindings. Check if you have added the the extention configuration to you service endpoints you want to have the behavior.

Comment: It does get called because the message contains other headers that I am adding in BeforeSendRequest. What is the extension configuration by the way?